# Is there any way that we can fail the build of an API on the basis of outcomes of Xunit test cases?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, nunit, xunit

Is there any way that we can fail the build of an API on the basis of outcomes of Xunit test cases?

Meaning that if one the Xunit test case fails then build of API/Solution will get failed . Means first when we click on run then Xunit test cases run and then on the basis of result we can decide about API/Soln build

We are using

.Net-4.6

Xunit-2.4.2

I tried to search on google but couldn't find anything regarding this can anyone please help

Comment: On the contrary, you need to build in able to have something to run the tests. What you are asking for could however be achieved by for example using a build pipeline in Azure Devops. You can then use a task for running the tests and one for the build of an artifact, and then fail the pipeline run if the test task fails.

Comment: Hi @kaffekopp Thanks for responding, I have researched about your solution but I want solution related to local machines of perticular developer since on Azure Devops will be too much late for us to realise that test case is failing